# Print contents of a PDF to the command line

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line, cat

I'm looking for a command-line program that will print out the text of a PDF file, just like `cat` for a text file.

I've found `pdftotxt`, and that would be workable, but I'd prefer something that replicates the `cat` functionality because I want to pipe to `grep`.  Thanks!

Comment: Though it does not look like it is a solution to this problem anyone interested in interacting with PDF files from the command line should be aware of [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). (And you could look at the `data_dump` command to see if anything useful can be obtained from it...)

Comment: Related: [PDF to text convertor](http://superuser.com/questions/286961/pdf-to-text-convertor)

Comment: Note that @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten's suggestion of `pdftk dump_data` does not convert the PDF contents to text, it dumps metadata about the PDF into a text file.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On the man pages for `pdftotext`, I found this:

> pdftotext [options] [PDF-file [text-file]]
>
> Description
> Pdftotext converts Portable Document Format (PDF) files to plain text.
>
> Pdftotext reads the PDF file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, text-file. If text-file is not specified, pdftotext converts file.pdf to file.txt. **If text-file is '-', the text is sent to stdout.**

Thus to output to `stdout` in order to pipe to `grep` use this:

```
pdftotext mydoc.pdf - | grep mysearchterm
```

Comment: Which seems to come with [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/portsntools.html) (a fact that may be useful when trying to figure out which package to install...)

Comment: See also [Is there a better pdf to text converter than pdftotext?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52040/is-there-a-better-pdf-to-text-converter-than-pdftotext)

Comment: Installation on Linux: `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`, OSX: `brew install poppler`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this: https://github.com/luochen1990/nodejs-easy-pdf-parser

It is a npm package and you need to install nodejs (and npm) to use it.

It can be used as a command line tool:

```
npm install -g easy-pdf-parser
pdf2text test.pdf > test.txt
```

And this tool will sort text lines by their y coordinates, so it works great at most case. And it also works well with unicode and cross platform (as comparison: mingw64's `pdftotext` will lose unicode characters on windows).

Comment: first pdf I tried it on gave an error: `(node:3972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pages' of undefined`

Comment: @masterxilo maybe that depends on the content of the pdf file, could you please submit an issue with your pdf file which has issue?

Comment: https://github.com/luochen1990/nodejs-easy-pdf-parser/issues/1